# Sklearn Binning Process - It is possible to return a interval?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, binning, discretization

I'm trying to use `KBinsDiscretizer` from `sklearn.preprocessing`, but it returns integer values as 1,2,..,N (representing the interval). Is it possible to return a correct interval as **(0.2, 0.5)** or this is not implemented yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html:

> Attributes:   n_bins_ : int array, shape (n_features,):
>
> ```
> Number of bins per feature. Bins whose width are too small (i.e., <= 1e-8) are removed with a warning. bin_edges_ : array of arrays,
> ```
>
> shape (n_features, ):

```
The edges of each bin. Contain arrays of varying shapes (n_bins_, ) Ignored features will have empty arrays.
```

This would mean a no in your case. There is also another hint:

````
The inverse_transform function converts the binned data into the original feature space. Each value will be equal to the mean of the two bin edges.```
````